# Want to convert my exesting application to support Multi Tenancy in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to convert my java application to support Multi Tenancy.
I have lots of configuration files, Data source files.
Is there any better architecture which I can follow to make my task easy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have tenant-specific customizations (which is usually the case in Enterprise applications), then you can do this without major changes in your application architecture. Data isolation is the only thing you have to really worry about. You will have to tag all your sessions to its corresponding tenant-ids(using a session variable)

In-case you have customizations, then you might have to revisit your architecture to introduce the variations.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx for multi-tenant data architectures.